# Rake commands that work over multiple rails_envs don't respect DATABASE_URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, environment-variables

I've got a rails application running in a docker container, and everything is fairly standard.

I've got an .env file that sets, among other things, the `DATABASE_URL` to `postgresql://postgres@db`

The application will boot, and interact with the database normally, but at setup, users need to run the `db:setup` rake tasks with explicit environments, otherwise only development follows `DATABASE_URL`.

For example, running `rake db:setup` will spit out errors about the test database missing on both the `db:create` and `db:seed` steps. Running `rake db:setup RAILS_ENV=development && rake db:setup RAILS_ENV=test`, however, works flawlessly.

Additionally, running `ActiveRecord::Base.configurations` shows the following:

```
{
  'default'     => {
    'adapter' => 'postgresql',
    'pool'    => 5,
    'timeout' => 5000
  },
  'development' => { 'adapter'  => 'postgresql',
                     'pool'     => 5,
                     'timeout'  => 5000,
                     'database' => 'xxxxxx_development',
                     'username' => 'postgres',
                     'host'     => 'db' },
  'test'        => { 'adapter'  => 'postgresql',
                     'pool'     => 5,
                     'timeout'  => 5000,
                     'database' => 'xxxxxx_test' },
  'production'  => { 'adapter'  => 'postgresql',
                     'pool'     => 5,
                     'timeout'  => 5000,
                     'database' => 'xxxxxx_production' }
}
```

You can see that `development` picked up the `host` value, but no other envs did.

Is this something on my end, or a bug in rails?

Comment: i assume you also have a database.yml present? do you know about how rails handles the preferences when both is present? http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#connection-preference

Comment: Yea I do have a database.yml, and I'm relying on the merge between them as outlined in that guide. The merging works for whatever RAILS_ENV is set to (i.e. the db name is properly set), but no secondary rails envs, like those invoked by db:setup. They purely match their yml configs

Comment: how are the .env variables exposed to the environment when running rake?

Comment: Docker-compose, via the env_file command. The variables show up inside the container when I check it with bash or similar commands, and ruby's ENV can see them